# .htaccess run XML file as PHP

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess

So I have a page domain.com/sitemap.php

I want to make it so that if I go to domain.com/sitemap.xml, it will be treated like the above URL.

I placed:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

in my .htaccess file but nothing is happening.

Comment: Considering that your last four questions where about mod_rewrite as well … it might be about time that you make an effort and go learn the basics of using it yourself by now.